# how to add Splash Screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.

I want to add a **Splash Screen** in my flutter app but I didn't find any accurate solution.

So, the question is:
**How can I add a splash screen in flutter?**

Comment: Are you looking for a way to show something while Flutter itself is initializing on a potato phone that does not have much performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your flutter project, you will find the android folder, in that folder, there is one file named Manifest and in that manifest file SplashScreenDrawable is defined, you need to edit that file. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfM3Q.png)

Add splash logo directly in to @drawable/launch_background in android folder.

Please find attachment.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/es4JO.png[![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es4JO.png%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1]][1]

Comment: This answer is the best and should be preferred.  However it would be great if you could show some real example. As this is not related to flutter and has to do more with android folder. So newbies can find it difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks, bro it Worked! there were two folders with launch_background.xml, drawable and drawable-v21. so I tried in drawable-v21 it worked. I checkout and got that drawable-v21 is for phones API level higher than 21 and drawable for lesser.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Splash Screen Widget and set this Widget as initial widget

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        new Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), onDoneLoading)
      }
    
      
    
      onDoneLoading() async {
        // SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Signup');
        // });
      }
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ...Your Widget 
        
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the official flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) for more info on this.

Anyway, You can add a splash screen in Flutter by using [splashscreen](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen) package as shown below :

```
class MySplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySplashState createState() => _MySplashState();
}

class _MySplashState extends State<MySplash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SplashScreen(
        title: new Text(
          'App Name',
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontFamily: 'MyFont'),
        ),
        seconds: 3,
        navigateAfterSeconds: new IntroScreenPage(),
        image: new Image.asset('images/dev.jpg'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
        photoSize: 100.0,
        loaderColor: Colors.blue,
        loadingText: Text(
          'Welcome to Flutter',
          style: GoogleFonts.ptSansNarrow(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```